# Spring Tool Suite: Copying and renaming a Maven Web App

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have a HelloWorld Java app called FitnessTracker that I want to clone as another name, FDE3, leaving the original website in tact. I performed the following steps an attempt to do this. Please tell me where I went wrong and/or what else I need to do.

[image: 1-Copy the project]
[image: 2-Paste the project]
[image: 3-Paste new as FDE3]
[image: 4-Select new FDE3]
[image: 5-Close the original]
[image: 6-Update POM step 1]
[image: 7-Update POM step 2]

Change Context Root

[image: Change Context Root]

Confirm Change Context Root

[image: Confirm Change tio Context Root]

Still the original "FitnessTracker" name persists and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

[image: Old Name Persists]

If I was able to successfully clone the FitnessTracker webapp as FDE3, I should be able to access the new site as

```
http://localhost:8080/FDE3
```

But I get an invalid resource error. Instead, the site is still accessible as

```
http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker
```

..because of reminants of the old name.

What do I need to change within Spring Tool Suite to get the web app to use only the new name? To minimize chance of corruptying the project, I'd rather do it via the STS GUI over manual modification of any system file.

I see that the following file contains the text "FitnessTracker" but I would rather not modify it manully for fear of breaking. What GUI option controls this?

```
Search "fitnesstracker" (2 hits in 1 file)
  C:\Dev\Workspace\FDE3\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component (2 hits)
    Line 2:     <wb-module deploy-name="FitnessTracker">
    Line 7:         <property name="java-output-path" value="/FitnessTracker/target/classes"/>
```

Sorry for being a noob.

**Update:**

I'm not sure what I did, maybe just clean, refresh, open/close a million time, dunno, but now when I run the web server from with the Spring IDE the site is coming up using the FDE3 path, however, I am wondering why I see a reference to Fitness in Parens in the project node.

[image]

Earlier, it just displayed "FitnessTracker" in parens, now I see a full path to a Test folder...

**Update 2:**

When I copied the FitnessTracker project  as FDE3, I didn't expect that the new FDE3 project would have any ties to FitnessTracker project and I didn't think that the new FD3 project would be in SVN until I added it to SVN, but based on the icons I see below, it looks like it is, (I'm new to SVN, too)

[image]

It looks like my issues are related to SVN.

[image]

Why is there a tie to the original FT project and why? How should I have clone the FitnessTracker project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your issue is indeed related to SVN. Copying an SVN working copy will copy `.svn` folders inside that and will be pointing to the same URL in the SVN repository. What you have to do is an SVN Export of your `FitnessTracker` project to `FitnessTracke-Ex` first in either Tortoise or Subclipse SVN client and then import that project into your STS Eclipse environment. Finally you can copy and rename the `FitnessTracke-Ex` project `FDE2` or `FDE3`

See  [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html)
 post on how to Export a working copy

See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm) post on how to Import an existing project into Eclipse